# What is the Attack Roll for Deflect Missile?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

I think I understand the basics of the ability that the Monk gets, but just wanted to check if I was right:

- If the Monk is successful at catching a missile and then throws it back at the target, do you roll a d20 + Dex + Proficiency bonus to hit, just as if it was a normal arrow fired from a bow (for example)?
- Then the damage caused is your Monk Dice (1d4 at level 1) + Dex?

Comment: [Related] [When does a monk have proficiency with deflected missiles?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65844)

Comment: May be prudent to also ask about the range of the attack for the purposes of determining advantage and disadvantage.

Answer (score 10):

Deflect Missile attacks are considered attacks with a monk weapon according to the feature description's last sentence and the [Sage Advice](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf) compendium question relating to it.

As such, due to the Martial Arts class feature, you are allowed to choose to use STR or DEX for the attack and damage bonuses. You also get your proficiency bonus for the attack roll as specifically stated by the Deflect Missiles class feature. In addition, the usual Martial Arts monk weapon rules of being able to choose the weapon's normal damage dice (the projectile/weapon's damage) or Martial Arts' monk weapon damage dice applies.

> **When a monk using Deflect Missiles catches and throws a projectile, what is the damage of the attack?**
>
> A missile counts as a monk weapon if thrown via Deflect
> Missiles; it deals its damage or Martial Arts damage (the
> monk’s choice).

To summarize, the attack roll is d20+(DEX or STR)+Proficiency, and the damage roll is (original weapon damage dice or Martial Arts' monk weapon damage dice) + (DEX or STR).

Worth noting is that, unlike the original ranged weapon attack targeted at the monk, you are limited to a 20/60 range on the Deflect Missiles attack as clarified by the [official PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf).

With the errata, the end of the latest Deflect Missiles feature description [now contains](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#DeflectMissiles):

> You make this attack with proficiency, regardless of your weapon proficiencies, and the missile counts as a monk weapon for the attack, which has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think the doc may have changed out from under me given that I originally answered this in 2016 but that line's no longer in 2016's errata doc, but the current version in the book states "You make this attack with proficiency, regardless of your weapon proficiencies, and the missile counts as a monk weapon for the attack, which has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.". Updating my link to the last '2017' errata which explicitly states the range change.

Comment: Thanks for adding in the text from the errata.

Answer (score 4):

The specific rule for *Deflect Missiles* is (PHB p.78):

> If you reduce the damage to 0, you can catch the
>   missile if it is **small enough for you to hold in one hand**
>   and you have at least one hand free. If you catch a
>   missile in this way, you can spend 1 ki point to **make a
>   ranged attack with the weapon or piece of ammunition**
>   you just caught, as part of the same reaction. You make
>   this **attack with proficiency**, regardless of your weapon
>   proficiencies, and the missile counts as **a monk weapon**
>   for the attack.

And from the errata:

> The range of the monk’s ranged attack is 20/60 feet.

The various *general* rules are:

- You are throwing the weapon - this normally uses your STR modifier unless the weapon possesses the *Finesse* property (p.147), however, you can use DEX because it is a *Monk Weapon* in this situation (p.78).
- Range is overridden by the specific.
- As a *Monk Weapon* you can choose to use the weapon's die or your Monk damage die (p.78).

**Examples**

- **Javelin** Range 20/60, DEX or STR + proficiency, 1d6 or Monk die damage
- **Crossbow quarrel** Range 20/60 (improvised), DEX or STR + proficiency, 1d4 (improvised) or Monk die damage
- **Handaxe** Range 20/60, DEX or STR + proficiency, 1d6 or Monk die damage
- **Battleaxe** Range 20/60 (improvised), DEX or STR + proficiency, 1d4 (improvised) or Monk die damage
- **Greataxe** N/A too big to fit in one hand

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95456/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-what-is-the-attack-roll-for-deflect-missile).